# Need help in configuring intellisense for python in vscode

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Need help to setup intellisense, autocomplete and code suggestion for Python in vscode

From my personal experience, it works only partially.

For instance, Below Works

```
import numpy as np
np.random.<autocomplete works>
```

But if I go and chain one more method, it stops autocompleting
Below does not work

```
rng = np.random.default_rng() 
rng.<autocomplete does not work>
```

I've tried many ways, but nothing seems to work. Many times even normal autocomplete from the core python module like String, List also stops working. I have to open Anaconda Spyder to do a autocomplete lookup and then use the correct one in vscode jupyter notebook

Any idea/suggestions will be helpful

Comment: At present, the intellisense and auto-completion functions of python in VSCode are provided by the python extension. For the requirements you describe, its prompt function needs to be further improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the cell,

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
```

Then, `rng.<tab>` will work.